# Should I use window or any filtering to average my data?

Tags: window-functions, moving-average, window

I have 80 seconds of data and I have to score my data by taking the average or median (or some other method) every 10 seconds. What's the best way to do this ? Should I just use a regular rectangular window or should I go into other FIR windowing? Should my window be overlapping/non-overlapping?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can I please ask if this was resolved?

Answer (score 0):

> I have 80 seconds of data and I have to score my data by taking the average or median (or some other method) every 10 seconds. What's the best way to do this ?

A [Moving Average Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)

> Should I just use a regular rectangular window or should I go into other FIR windowing?

The "window" in "Moving Average Window" has nothing to do with the "window" in ["Window function"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function).

> Should my window be overlapping/non-overlapping?

By definition, the moving average filter is applied in an overlapping fashion to the signal.

Say for example that your original signal is in some $x[n]$ with $n \in [0..N-1]$ and $N$ being the length of the signal. A 4 tap moving average filter is like taking the mean of 4 sequential values and **sliding** it over the whole duration of $x[n]$.

To obtain the arithmetic mean of a signal in this way you would do:

$$y[n]=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{3} x[n+k]$$

To produce $y[0]$ you work on the *window* $0..3$ over $x$

To produce $y[1]$ you work on the *window* $1..4$ over $x$

To produce $y[2]$ you work on the *window* $2..5$ over $x$

And so on...

Since the signal $x[n]$ is defined between $0..N-1$, the valid values for $y[n]$ are between $0..N-1-4$ (or $0..N-5$). It is possible to extend $y[n]$ to the same length as $x[n]$ by assuming that $x[n]$ is $0$ outside of the observation (that is, outside of the 80 seconds of signal that you have the signal drops to zero). But in that case, those last 4 values would be unreliable because we do not really know what was actually hapenning to the system that the signal is obtained from.

A moving average filter (specifically) can be implemented via convolution by observing that all that we do by obtaining the arithmetic mean over a sliding window is to multiply those *windows* of $x[n]$ with 4 identical numbers ($\frac{1}{4}$) and sum the result which is exactly the way [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) is defined.

To generalise, an M-tap moving average filter would look like $h = [\frac{1}{M},\frac{1}{M},...,\frac{1}{M}]$ and the simplest way to apply it in a MATLAB-like language is `y = conv(x, 1./ones(1,M))`. (Try it with something like `y = conv(x, [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25])`.

To transfer it to your specific setting, you have 80 seconds of data to be averaged over a 10 second interval. If you divide your signal in 8 non-overlapping windows (0-9, 10-19, 20-29, 30-39, ...70-79), you will get 8 instances of what the value of the average of the signal. You would then know that in the first 10 seconds the average was some value and in the next 10 seconds it jumped to another value but you would have lost what happened in between. Did it jump? Did it vary progressively? If you apply a moving average filter (again, with a 10 second time constant) you would obtain a smoothly varying view of the evolution of the mean.

The arithmetic mean though is by definition a linear multiply-and-accumulate kind of operation and it was possible to be implemented with convolution.

If you wanted to compute some other expression in a *sliding window* fashion over $x$, you would probably have to do it manually. For example:

```
for n=0:N-1-M
    y(n) = someFunction(x(n:n+M-1))
```

And within `someFunction` you can have whatever processing you like over the subsegment of $x$ between the $n$ and $n+M-1$ samples.

That processing **might** require that you modify the overlapping of the windows **and / or** a window function.

For example when computing a [Spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram) you apply a [Discrete Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) in overlapping *sliding windows* over some $x$.

Now, when referring **specifically** to the DFT, in addition to these overlapping $x[n]$ segments you might also have to decide on a window function to reduce [spectral leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Spectral_analysis).

Hope this helps.

Comment: *"The 'window' in 'Moving Average Window' has nothing to do with the 'window' in 'Window function'."*   $$ $$ i dunno that i would agree with that claim.

Comment: From a mathematical point of view, the way to select things out of a set (whatever the set flavour) is with an [index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_set). To **define** a [window function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#A_list_of_window_functions) you use $N$. $N$ is the size of the index set. Therefore, **selection** of the specific values is one thing ("window" as a *buffer*) and **shaping** of those values is another ("window" as "spectral window"). You can use a boxcar to select parts of a signal but you cannot use a Blackman-Harris to select **and** "shape".

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson ...for a "demo" of selecting parts of a signal by crafting boxcars (or constructing index sets), please see [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/45212/best-way-to-process-this-signal/45213#45213), section *"Detect the presence of the face..."*. Also, I did not add your username in my previous comment so you might want to check that first.

Comment: So I decided to do moving average using the following piece of code in matlab.
B = 1/10*ones(10,1)
filter(B,1,input)
I am having some issues. I have 80 samples of data which is all above 0.9. When I did the moving average, my first ~10 values out  are below 0.9. Can someone explain to me what I did wrong here?

Comment: @Baid Can you please amend your question with what you mention in this comment? It will then be visible to everyone in DSP.SE. As a simple comment to my answer I am the only one who gets the notification about it.